# How to set API Server parameters on kubespray deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I am using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray) for the deployment of a kubernetes cluster and 
want to set some API Server parameters for the deployment. In specific I want to configure the authentication via OpenID Connect (e.g set the [`oidc-issuer-url`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuring-the-api-server) parameter). I saw that kubespray has some vars to set (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/vars.md), but not the ones I am looking for.

Is there a way to set these parameters via kubespray? I don't want to configure each master manually (e.g by editing the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` files).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [k8s-cluster.yml](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/b708db4cd5256e2c114ff872d4a7a56e86b7ac34/inventory/sample/group_vars/k8s-cluster/k8s-cluster.yml#L63) file has some parameters which allow to set the OID configuration:

```
kube_oidc_auth: true
...
kube_oidc_url: https:// ...
kube_oidc_client_id: kubernetes
kube_oidc_ca_file: "{{ kube_cert_dir }}/ca.pem"
kube_oidc_username_claim: sub
kube_oidc_username_prefix: oidc:
kube_oidc_groups_claim: groups
kube_oidc_groups_prefix: oidc:
```

These parameters are the counter parts to the [oidc api server parameters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuring-the-api-server)

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom of the page you are referring to there is description how to define custom flags for various components of k8s:

```
kubelet_custom_flags:
  - "--eviction-hard=memory.available<100Mi"
  - "--eviction-soft-grace-period=memory.available=30s"
  - "--eviction-soft=memory.available<300Mi"
```

The possible vars are:

```
apiserver_custom_flags
controller_mgr_custom_flags
scheduler_custom_flags
kubelet_custom_flags
kubelet_node_custom_flags
```